# How to use _timestamp in logstash elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to figure out how to use the [_timestamp](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html) with logstash.

I have tried to add to the mapping:

```
   "_timestamp" : {
      "enabled" : true,
      "path" : "@timestamp"
   },
```

But that does not have the expected effect. I did this in the `elasticsearch-template.json` file (I tried with and without the `"store"=true`):

```
{
  "template" : "logstash-*",
  "settings" : {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
       "_timestamp" : {
          "enabled" : true,
          "store" : true,
          "path" : "@timestamp"
       },

       "_all" : {"enabled" : true},
       "dynamic_templates" : [ {
  .....
```

And I added the modified file to the output filter

```
output {
  elasticsearch_http {
    template => '/tmp/elasticsearch-template.json'
    host => '127.0.0.1'
    port=>9200
  }
}
```

In order to make sure the database is clean I repeatedly do:

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/logstash*
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/_template/logstash
rm ~/.sincedb_*
```

and then I try to import my logfile. But for some reasons, the `_timestamp` is not set.

The mapping seems to be ok

```
{
  "logstash-2014.03.24" : {
    "_default_" : {
      "dynamic_templates" : [ {
        "string_fields" : {
          "mapping" : {
            "index" : "analyzed",
            "omit_norms" : true,
            "type" : "string",
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "index" : "not_analyzed",
                "ignore_above" : 256,
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string"
        }
      } ],
      "_timestamp" : {
        "enabled" : true,
        "store" : true,
        "path" : "@timestamp"
      },
      "properties" : {
        "@version" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed",
          "omit_norms" : true,
          "index_options" : "docs"
        },
        "geoip" : {
          "dynamic" : "true",
          "properties" : {
            "location" : {
              "type" : "geo_point"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "logs" : {
      "dynamic_templates" : [ {
        "string_fields" : {
          "mapping" : {
            "index" : "analyzed",
            "omit_norms" : true,
            "type" : "string",
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "index" : "not_analyzed",
                "ignore_above" : 256,
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string"
        }
      } ],
      "_timestamp" : {
        "enabled" : true,
        "store" : true,
        "path" : "@timestamp"
      },
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
        },
```

The documents in the database look like

```
 {
    "_id": "Cps2Lq1nTIuj_VysOwwcWw", 
    "_index": "logstash-2014.03.25", 
    "_score": 1.0, 
    "_source": {
      "@timestamp": "2014-03-25T00:47:09.703Z", 
      "@version": "1", 
      "created": "2014-03-25 01:47:09,703", 
      "host": "macbookpro.fritz.box", 
      "message": "2014-03-25 01:47:09,703 - Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost", 
      "path": "/Users/scharf/git/ckann/annotator-store/logs/requests.log", 
      "text": "Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost"
    }, 
    "_type": "logs"
  },
```

why is the `_timestamp` not set???

Answer (score 2):

In short, it does work.

I tested your exact scenario and here's what I found:

When using _source enabled and specifying `_timestamp` from some path in the `_source`, 
you will never see `_timestamp` as part of the document, but if however, you add the `?fields` query string part, for example:

`http://<localhost>:9200/es_test_logs/ESTest1/ilq4PU3tR9SeoLo794wZlg?fields=_timestamp`
you will get the correct `_timestamp` value.

If, instead of using path, you pass `_timestamp` externally (in the `_source` document), you will see `_timestamp` under the `_source` property in the document as normal.

If you disable the `_source` field, you will not see ANY property at all in the document, even those you set as "`store" : true`. You will only see them when specifying `?fields`, or when building a query that returns those fields.